# the moment set of unitary representation of lie groups, analogue in the p-adic case

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups, unitary-representations

Let $G$ be a real Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\pi$ a unitary representation of $G$ on a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_{\pi}$. Note $\mathcal{H}_{\pi}^{\infty}$ the space of $C^{\infty}$ vectors for $\pi$. Let $\mathfrak{g}^{*}$
be the dual space of $\mathfrak{g}$. Wildberger defined the moment map $\Psi_{\pi}$ of $\pi$ as follows : 
For all $\xi\in\mathcal{H}_{\pi}^{\infty}\backslash
\{0\}$, the element $\Psi_{\pi}(\xi)\in\mathfrak{g}^{*}$ is defined by : 
$$\Psi_{\pi}(\xi)(X)=\frac{1}{i}\frac{<d\pi(X)\xi,\xi>_{\mathcal{H}_{\pi}}}{<\xi,\xi>_{\mathcal{H}_{\pi}}},~~~X\in\mathfrak{g}.$$
The moment set $I_{\pi}$ of the representation $\pi$ is by definition the closure in $\mathfrak{g}^*$ of the
image of the moment map: $\Psi_{\pi}:\mathcal{H}_{\pi}^{\infty}\backslash
\{0\}\longrightarrow\mathfrak{g}^*$. Wildberger has proved that the moment set
for $\pi$ coincides with the closure of the convex hull of the corresponding coadjoint
orbit.

My question : Is there an analog of the notion of moment set for the unitary smooth representations of a p-adic group ?